# How to add a dependency from examples on tests in build.gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am able to run `./gradlew compileTestJava`, but `./gradlew compileExamplesJava` is failing.
This is my project structure:

```
src/examples/org
└── eclipse
    └── paho
        └── client
            └── mqttv3
                ├── internal
                │   ├── security
                │   ├── websocket
                │   └── wire
                ├── logging
                ├── persist
                └── util
src/examples/test/
src/tests/org/
└── eclipse
    └── paho
        └── client
            └── mqttv3
                └── test
                    ├── automaticReconnect
                    ├── client
                    ├── connectionLoss
                    ├── logging
                    ├── properties
                    └── utilities
```

The file in folder `jpf-core/src/examples/test` imports some files that are present under `jpf-core/src/tests/org`. How should I add this dependency in build.gradle? Right now, my build.gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: "java"

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.palantir.gradle.gitversion:gradle-git-version:0.11.0"
    }
}


dependencies {
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
    testCompile "org.ow2.asm:asm:7.1"
    implementation "org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.1.0"
    examplesImplementation files("build")
}

task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.testCompile
    into 'build'
}
```

Gradle does not recognize this line: `examplesImplementation files("build")`

Comment: the configuration examplesImplementation does not seem to exist, also trying to add dependencies by using `files("build")` is not a great idea.
Perhaps you can explain in a little more words what you are trying to achieve and what your project setup looks like

Comment: @p.streef I have updated the question with my project setup. Basically, sampleTest.java is present under `src/examples/test/` that refers to the files from src/tests. I am getting  "package does not exist" errors.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from your updated question you are looking for sourcesets.
By default, a java project contains 2 source sets:
main (src/main/java & src/main/resource) and test (src/test/java & src/test/resources) where test "depends on" (or actually extends from) main.

From your question it seems you want a "tests" sourceset that can be used from an "examples" sourceset. I think what you should do looks something like this:

```
sourceSets {
    tests {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["src/tests"]
        }
        //if required:
        //resources {
        //    srcDirs = ["resources/tests"]
        //}
    }
    examples {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["src/examples"]
        }
        //if required:
        //resources {
        //    srcDirs = ["resources/examples"]
        //}
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.tests.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.tests.output
    }
    
}

configurations {
    examplesImplementation.extendsFrom implementation
    examplesRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom runtimeOnly
}
```

This will tell gradle where to expect your source files and should also make the tests files available to examples.

And after telling you all this I would like to point out that I would not advise you to deviate from the default sourcesets unless you have a good reason (and understanding). So if you don't you might want to just stick with the normal main/test sourcesets (and perhaps extand a new sourceset from one of those)